# If $H$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^l$, is $A*H$ a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^l$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $H$ is a $k$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^l$, $k\leq l$. 
Let $A$ be an $l\times l$ matrix in $\mathbb{R}^l $ positive definite.

Is $A*H$ a $k$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^l$, where "$*$" denotes the product of each vector of $H$ by the matrix $A$? Is the fact that $A$ is positive definite a necessary/sufficient condition?

This question is from van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistic" p.232 when the author discusses the application of lemma 16.6 to the likelihood ratio statistic.

Comment: In what context is this? You should note that in general the rank of A will be an important factor if you want to preserve the dimension of the subspace. If it's full rank you're fine, and even in certain situations not being full rank is fine.

Comment: I have added some clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sufficient condition is for $A$ to be invertible.

More precisely, if $k>0$, then

> If $A\in \mathbb R^{l\times l}$ is a matrix, then it is invertible if and only if for every $k$-dimensional subspace $H$ of $\mathbb R^l$, then $AH$ is again a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^l$.

If $A$ is positive definite, then it is invertible, so the propriety holds.

Notice also that if you fix the subspace $H$, then there are also some non-invertible $A$ such that $AH$ is still a $k$-dimensional subspace, like, for example, the projection on $H$ itself.